# 70s-ish show about Earth's timeline into the future

Tags: story-identification

I seem to remember a hosted show that went through Earth's timeline from that point, the 70s, to a future world. It described what advances we should reach and what technology would be.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I assume this was a TV show?  What country did you watch it in?  Do you recall the channel?  Was there just one presenter?  Were the advances just described or were they animated?

Comment: Without further details, this feels like any number of DIsney "in the future" presentations.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.. I have been trying to track this show down for years. Yes it was a tv show, watched in the US (NY), wish I could recall the channel, it was advances and not animated, with only one presenter.

Comment: Sounds a little like ["Beyond 2000"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Tomorrow_(TV_series)) but the dates are wrong

Answer (score 3):

I am going to suggest "[The 21st Century](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0287889/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3)" hosted by Walter Cronkite. It was on from 1967 to 1969, so a little too early from what you said. It covered new discoveries in technology and did speculate what the future would be like, but it was organized by topic rather than going through the future decade by decade as a "timeline".

Here is a sample from Youtube:
[Autos and All That Traffic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3GW3AYR__U)